# Swift: Строка поиска в tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

У меня есть tablewView со списком городом и строка поиска над ней. Если городов много - хочется дать юзеру возможность использовать поиск.

Вывожу данные следующим образом:

У меня есть класс:

```swift
class City {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
}
```

Я получаю список городов и их ID и создаю массив класса City, который заполняю полученными данными. Сразу же создаю массив filteredData, который при инициализации у меня равен списку всех городов - на основе этого массива я обновляю таблицу.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadCity() // Тут скрипт, который загружает список городов в массив citiesList 

        searchBarController.delegate = self
        filteredCitiesList = citiesList

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return filteredCitiesList.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredCitiesList[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }
```

Дальше я, собственно, пытаюсь реализовать изменение массива filteredCitiesList если юзер вводит данные в поиск и обновить таблицу, но не могу точно понять как это сделать.

Вот код, который я нашёл. Вероятно он бы работал, если бы у меня был просто массив String, но т.к у меня массив объектов собственного класса (City), то он ругается ("'String' is not convertible to 'City'"), а как поправить моих знаний уже не хватает. Хелп)

```swift
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredCitiesList = searchText.isEmpty ? citiesList : citiesList.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел способ реализовать задачу, если кому-то будет тоже интересно - вот финальный рабочий вариант:

```swift
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredCitiesList = citiesList
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {

            func filterTableView(text:String) {
                let search = text.lowercased()
                filteredCitiesList = citiesList.filter({ (mod) -> Bool in
                    return mod.name!.lowercased().contains(search)
                })
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            filterTableView(text: searchText)
        }
    }
```